# Php doctrine setup

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I want to start learing using doctrine ORM with php.

I did thist tutorial : 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

I placed "vendor" folder generated by composer,  in root directory of my application.

I created the bootstrap, and successfully connected to mysql."

I got stuck at "Generating the Database Schema " .
If i want to generate the mysql table using " $ php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create "

This is what i get:

!/usr/bin/env sh
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"

cd "`dirname "$0"`"

cd "../doctrine/orm/bin"

BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/doctrine.php"

cd "$SRC_DIR"

"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"

What's wrong?
[image]

Comment: There are also a bin folder in vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/ you can use this one like this

   php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

make sure you have root folder and a cli-config.php file is present in root folder.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/_ph183Kh-5o/_P_coljB-dcJ

Answer (score 2):

Change the path in your command as it's shown bellow:

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

I've found solution [here](http://www.agevaled.com/2013/10/09/doctrine2-getting-started-issues/2147483647/)